# Packaging electron produces blank page with no content

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I've built this app using electron: https://github.com/harryingles/FRJumpCalc

However I can't seem to get it package into an exe file - doing this with any of the packaging utilities causes a blank page when I open it.

http://prntscr.com/hutb0j

This is my first Electron project.

**EDIT**: I installed a module to open the Dev Tools: and was given the following error message when running the app from the exe file when packaged -

Not allowed to load local resource: file:///views/index.html

Comment: what does devtools say in packaged app? I have rough guess it might missing deps you installed via bower but can't confirm.

Comment: I've edited the post to show what my dev tools said

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this by:

Changing the pathname of the page to __dirname + "build/index.html"

and adding

"files: [
"build",
"*.js",
"public"]

to my package.json (It is not updated in the github repo if anybody needs it)